# Second RTCPeerConnection stuck in "connecting" state, while first connection successfully connects

Tags: webrtc

So I'm trying to set up a 3-way video call with `WebRTC`.

The first two connections connect fine. I have it set up so that the third person to join the room sends an offer to the first 2 sockets in the room (I'm using `Node.js socket.io` as a signalling server). The offer successfully sends to both sockets, and both sockets send back their answers. Both answers contain 1 audio track and 1 video track, however, for some reason, the connection only works with one of them.

The result is that with 3 users, the first user (usually) ends up seeing both peers, and then the second and third people only see one other person. When I look at the `connectionState` for each peer connection, one of them is stuck in "connecting", while everything else looks fine.

[image: Here's a picture of the connection object]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating a new PeerConnection for the first two people in the room? When you say `first 2 sockets` it sounds like you are trying to use the same PeerConnection for multiple connections.

Each PeerConnection is only for a 1:1 connection. What you are trying to create is a `Mesh Topology` I believe.

Comment: Yes, I'm creating new PeerConnections, each connection is 1:1. When there are only 2 people in the room, there are 2 PeerConnections, when a third person joins, there are a total of 6.

Comment: I don't have enough info to say for sure, but it sounds like something is going wrong with signaling. Is it possible that the Offer/Answer and ICECandidates weren't successfully exchanged? It is also possible it could be stuck in connecting because they really can't connect, are you using STUN and TURN (UDP, TCP and TLS)?

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but offers and answers all seem to be exchanged properly between all the peers, ice candidates are being sent, tracks are added to all peer connections and the logs for the one client that successfully sees both the other peers are exactly the same as the logs for the other two clients where they can only see one other person. The only difference is that for the clients that can only see one other person, no video plays after I set the srcObject of the video element. The media stream looks okay, it contains both a video and audio track but nothing plays.

Comment: And sorry I forgot to mention, yes I'm using STUN and TURN servers and they have been working great for months, just no luck with getting more than 2 people on a call.